# Symfony 6 : Login impossible (nothing happens)

Tags: authentication, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony6

I hope you'll help me...

When I try to login on my Symfony 6 app, nothing happens. I have no error, but it don't log me. It only refresh the page.

**security.yaml**

```
security:
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email

    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            security: false
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator:
                - App\Security\AppAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                target: login
        secured_area:
            pattern:   ^/
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
```

**SecurityController::login**

```
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils, $errorLog = null): Response
    {
        if ($this->getUser()) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_dashboard');
        }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        // var_dump($errorLog);

        return $this->render('public/auth/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername, 
            'error' => $error
        ]);
    }
```

**My prod server is up to date and I can log me**, but in dev (127.0.0.1) it's impossible.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have disabled security layer in the main firewall. Try to remove `security: false`in the main firewall:

```yaml
# security.yaml
security:
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email

    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            # security: false # REMOVE THIS LINE
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator:
                - App\Security\AppAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                target: login
        secured_area:
            pattern:   ^/
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
password_hashers:
   App\Entity\User:
      algorithm: auto

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have blindly followed interface

```
\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::eraseCredentials
```

and removed those

```
public function eraseCredentials(): void
{
    $this->password = null;
    $this->email = null;
}
```

Result was same as for `security: false`, login proceed without error, but nothing happens in fact and I staid on the login page.